# Applying a Read Write Lock to a Single Linked List Data Strcture?

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures, concurrency

I have coded the Read/Write lock as follows -:

```
public class ReadWriteLocks {


    private volatile int numberOfReaders = 0;
    private volatile int numberOfWriters = 0;
    private volatile int numberOfWriteRequests = 0;


    public int getNumberOfReaders() {
        return this.numberOfReaders;
    }


    public int getNumberOfWriters() {
        return this.numberOfWriters;
    }


    public int getNumberOfWriteRequests() {
        return this.numberOfWriteRequests;
    }


    public synchronized void lockRead() throws InterruptedException {

        while (numberOfWriters > 0 || numberOfWriteRequests > 0)
            this.wait();

        // increment the number of readers
        ++numberOfReaders;
    }


    public synchronized void unlockRead() {

        // decrement the number of readers
        --numberOfReaders;
        notifyAll();
    }


    public synchronized void lockWrite() throws InterruptedException {

        // increase the number of write requests
        ++numberOfWriteRequests;

        while (numberOfReaders > 0 || numberOfWriters > 0)
            this.wait();

        --numberOfWriteRequests;
        ++numberOfWriters;
    }
    public synchronized void unlockWrite() {

        // decrement the number of writers
        --numberOfWriters;

        // notify all the threads
        this.notifyAll();
    }

}
```

But how do I apply this lock to the readers and the writers method in my single linked list class, the reader method being the "getNthElement()" and "searchList()" and writer method's being "insert()" and "delete()" respectively. kindly help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
public Object getNthElement(int n) {
    try {
        myLock.lockRead();
        // fetch element;
        return element;
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        // If you don't want this exception to propagate, then the correct 
        // thing to do is set the "interrupted" flag again.
        Thread.interrupt(Thread.currentThread());
    } finally {
        myLock.unlockRead();
    }
}
```

However, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here, either by implementing a custom lock type or by implementing your own linked list type.  Perfectly good implementations of both are provided by the standard Java SE class library.

Comment: Thanks for replying stephen, I actually did what you wrote above, but is it guaranteed that the lock implementation I have done will work as there are no atomic operations, also if you can point out other errors it would be great. Also take into consideration that I need to implement a coarse grain read /write lock on my data structure, so does this implementation fit into that definition?

Comment: I cannot see any bugs in your lock class.  But that's not what you asked.  And if you do want a code review, you should be posting to codereview.stackexchange.com, not here.

Comment: ok, thanks for telling there are no bugs in my lock class, but will this work for multithreaded linked lists is what I am asking, where multiple threads are contending for a read and a write.

Comment: I thought I just answered that.

Comment: I am actually trying to learn multi-threading by implementing simple data structures and making them multi-threaded but just can't seem to get every aspect of the code right as I am getting confused as I think more about the number of situations that can happen :(